# Why does sage solve() return another equation(when it is clearly simple and solvable)

Tags: sage

I am trying to solve a simple equation on sage with the given data:

```
a=var("a")
x=vector([1,1])
y=vector([2,3])
A=matrix(2,2,[a,-1,-1,1])
```

I want to solve the equation:

```
f= ((x*A*y)/((sqrt(x*A*x)*sqrt(y*A*y))))==1/2
```

which returns :

(2*sqrt(a - 1)/sqrt(4*a - 3) == (1/2)

solving f for a returns:

```
solve(f,a)
```

[sqrt(a - 1) == 1/4*sqrt(4*a - 3)]

while this equation is easily solvable by hand.
Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Would this perhaps be more suitable on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Sage is not implementing every possible way to search for a solution. In my way of using it, the combination of human (structural) insight and the computational power of the machine always works best.

Why do we have the half-way answer? In our case `f` is an equation,

```
sage: f
2*sqrt(a - 1)/sqrt(4*a - 3) == (1/2)
```

which is not really an algebraic equation. (Square roots appear in there.)
The documentation of `solve`, ask for it via `solve?` or `?solve` or... , mentions this algebraic character wanted for the involved equations / expressions. Sage may try on its own to get an algebraic version, but this is too much a voluntary step, depending on the typed solve command line.

So it is a normal fact to get an "echo" of the equation.

Note however, that involving an other solver helps (in this case):

```
sage: solve(f, a, algorithm='sympy')
[a == (13/12)]
```